# how to redirect user for accessing to a page from URL in java?

Tags: java

I am coming to a problem where I have loginFilter where I dont want the user to access a page when they are logged in with the URL. So, all I want to do is redirect the user to the `index` page. Here is my code below. Thank you.

```
    public class LoginFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest)request;
        String username = req.getHeader("username");
        String password = req.getHeader("password");
        if(username == null) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        try {
            req.login(username, password);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } catch (ServletException e) {
            ((HttpServletResponse)response).setStatus(StatusCodes.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your method as :

```
HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse)response;
try {
    req.login(username, password);
    res.sendRedirect("/index");
} catch (ServletException e) {        

    // you can use SC_UNAUTHORIZED(401) from HttpServletResponse class as well
    res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```